# Create views based on amount of items in an array

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I am working on a quiz application, where I get the quiz items from an api. Right now, each question consist of an image and 4 possible answers. Currently, I have two views attached to my view controller(front view and back view), and they change to one and other, when an answer button is clicked(I am only displaying the first two questions this way).

Right now with each api call, I get 7 items(meaning 1 image and 4 answers for each item). But amount of questions can change anytime, **so I am trying to implement a way to automate the view creation process.**

Based on what I searched this is what I was able to come up with it:

QuizMainViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface QuizMainViewController: UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,retain)NSArray *results;
@property (nonatomic,assign)NSUInteger currentItemIndex; 
@property(nonatomic,assign)NSUInteger  numberOfItemsIntheResultsArray;
```

QuizMainViewController.m

```
#import "QuizMainViewController.m"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Base64.h"
#import "Item.h"
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface QuizMainViewController ()

@property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UIView *frontView;
@property (nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UIView *BackView;

//first view outlets
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *frontViewImage;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIButton *frontViewAnswer1;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIButton *frontViewAnswer2;
@property (nonatomic,weak)IBOutlet UIButton *frontViewAnswer3;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIButton *frontViewAnswer4;

//second view outlets
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *backViewImage;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIButton *backViewAnswer1;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIButton *backViewAnswer2;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIButton *backViewAnswer3;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIButton *backViewAnswer4;



@implementation QuizMainViewController

//the method that I am making the api call

-(void)loadQuizObjectsMethod
{
// this is the part I make the call and try to set the views based on if the items.count is odd or even.
operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id jsonObject)
                 {
                     NSArray *array = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"Items"];
                     NSLog(@"Item array: %@",array);
                     NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                     for (NSDictionary * itemDict in array) {
                         Item *myResponseItems = [[Item alloc] initWithDictionary:itemDict];
                         [tempArray addObject:myResponseItems];
                     }
                     _results = tempArray;
//this is where I need help with

                     Item *item = [_results objectAtIndex:_numberOfItemsIntheResultsArray];
                     for (_numberOfItemsIntheResultsArray in _results) {
                         if (_currentItemIndex %2 == 0) {
                          _currentItemIndex
                             //implement the front view
                         }else if (_currentItemIndex %2 == 1)
                         {
                             //implement the back view
                         }

                     }
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you want a separate view for each question? Why not just change the content of frontView and backView when the question changes?

Comment: @rdelmar, thank you for the reply, and that is exactly what I am trying to accomplish. I am saving the JSONitems in an array called results and get the array count, and save it to an nsinteger. Then based on the number of item objects, I want to call the front and back views for each question,(that is why I wrote an if for even and odd, which I believe I need to use nsindexpath instead of nsinteger).

Comment: @rdelmar, hi, could you look at this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310831/token-is-saved-but-unable-to-bypass-the-login-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `UIPageViewController` class in such situations. First create a class called `QuestionViewController` as follows

QuestionViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIButton *answer1;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIButton *answer2;
@property (nonatomic,weak)IBOutlet UIButton *answer3;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIButton *answer4;

@property (strong, nonatomic) Item *questionDetailsFromJSON;
```

QuestionViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   self.image = self.questionDetailsFromJSON.image
   //set all remaining outlets similar to this.
}
```

In the storyboard or xib embed a `UIPageViewController` in your `QuizMainViewController` using a`UIContainer`. Set `QuizMainViewController` as the delegate to the page view controller.

Change your QuizMainViewController.m as follows

```
@interface QuizMainViewController ()

@property(nonatomic,weak)IBOutlet UIPageViewController *pvc;

@implementation QuizMainViewController

//Implement all of the other methods

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
{
   int index = [self.results indexOfObject:[(QuestionViewController *)viewController    question]];
   index++;
   QuestionViewController *qvc = nil;
   if(index<self.results.count)
   {
     qvc = //Instantiate from story board or xib
     qvc.questionDetailsFromJSON = [self.results objectAtIndex:index];      
   }
   return qvc;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
{
   int index = [self.results indexOfObject:[(QuestionViewController *)viewController    question]];
   index--;
   QuestionViewController *qvc = nil;

   if(index>=0)
   {
     qvc = //Instantiate from story board or xib
     qvc.questionDetailsFromJSON = [self.results objectAtIndex:index];
   }

   return qvc;
}
```

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/) for further details.

Comment: thank you the reply. But I did not understand how this solution going to help me(I looked at that tutorial as well). Because, based on what you wrote, I still need to assign the values to the appropriate JSON items manually. I am looking for a way that if api sends 8 questions instead of 7, the method needs to be able to create an extra view for that question without changing the code.

Comment: You will be creating the view controllers in `pageViewController: viewControllerBeforeViewController:` and `pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:` based on the number of items in your array created using the JSON objects. So you just return nil when you reach the end of you array.

Comment: Ok. I ll try and let you know.

Comment: See my edit. This should help you understand better.

Comment: at the moment, this is how I am setting the first question.    Item *item =[_results objectAtIndex:0]; // to get the first item
                     
                     self.frontViewImage.image = item.image;//sets the image in the first item.
                     [_frontViewAnswer1 setTitle:[item.Answers objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the first answer from the first item. So when you say i need to set these in viewdidload, how I am going to automate this part? Since the number of items are not constant.

Comment: Edited the answer again. The questionViewController will hold a reference to your Item object.

Comment: I ended up creating my own solution,but this is also a good an example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The other poster's suggestion about using a page view controller is good. That would let you manage the pages with questions on them in a nice clean way.

As to your question of a variable number of fields on the form:

The simplest thing to do is to build your form for the maximum number of questions. Then, when you display it, hide those buttons/images that are not used for the current question.

You can create outlets for each button/image and then manipulate them directly, or you can assign tag numbers to them. If you use tag numbers it's a little easier to write code that shows the correct number of answer buttons.

Alternatively you could write code that creates and adds the buttons to the view controller hierarchy on the fly, but creating view objects directly in code is a little more work than doing it with IB. That's more than I can explain in detail in a forum post. For that, you should probably search for a tutorial on creating buttons through code rather than IB. It end up being like 4 or 5 lines of code per button.

A rough outline of the steps: You have to create a button using initWithFrame or the UIButton buttonWithType class method. You have to add a target/action to the button. You have to set it's title. You have to set it's frame, you have to save a pointer to it in an instance variable or an array, and you have to add it as a subview to your view controller's content view.