# token is saved but unable to bypass the login page

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, afnetworking

I am trying to bypass the login page to welcome page if the person already have a token. I am using basic auth and afnetworking for the api call. Once the user logs the username&password, I  base 64 the info and get a token. I save the token in a nsobject class where I create a token singleton and a simple is logged in method where it checks if the user has the token or not. But for some reason I always see the login page(meaning it skips my condition method). If any one can point out where I am making the mistake, it would be great.

This is class where I create the login singleton

**CredentialStore.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "LoginInfo.h"
@interface CredentialStore : NSObject
-(BOOL)isLoggedIn;
@property (nonatomic) LoginInfo *loginInfo;
+(id)sharedStore;
@end
```

**CredentialStore.m**

```
#import "CredentialStore.h"

static CredentialStore *sharedInsance;

@implementation CredentialStore

+(id)sharedStore
{
    if (!sharedInsance) {
        sharedInsance = [[CredentialStore alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInsance;
}

- (BOOL)isLoggedIn {
    return (self.loginInfo.authToken != nil);
}
@end
```

this is my authenticationapimanager class

**AuthAPIManager.h**

```
#import "AFHTTPSessionManager.h"
@interface AuthAPIManager : AFHTTPSessionManager
+ (id)sharedManager;
@end
```

**AuthAPIManager.m**

```
#import "AuthAPIManager.h"
#import "CredentialStore.h"

#define BASE_URL @"http://Url"
#define Base_Proxy @"http://Url"

static AuthAPIManager *sharedManager;

@implementation AuthAPIManager

//Setup the singleton to use throught the life of the application

+(id)sharedManager
{
    if (!sharedManager) {
        sharedManager = [[AuthAPIManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Base_Proxy]];
    }
    return sharedManager;
}
-(id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

this is the class where I save the login information

**LoginInfo.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface LoginInfo : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSNumber *AccountId;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *DeviceType;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *HardwareId;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *NickName;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *authToken;
-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
@end
```

**LoginInfo.m**

```
#import "LoginInfo.h"
@implementation LoginInfo
-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    self =[super init];
    if (self) {
        self.AccountId = [dictionary objectForKey:@"AccountId"];
        self.DeviceType = [dictionary objectForKey:@"DeviceType"];
        self.HardwareId = [dictionary objectForKey:@"HardwareId"];
        self.NickName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"NickName"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and in my view controller, in viewwillappearmethod, I check if the user has a token or not but this is the part I am having problems with

**LoginViewController.m**

```
@interface LoginViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) CredentialStore *credentialStore;
@end
implementation LoginViewController

#pragma mark - UIViewController
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self checkIfThePersonLoggedIn];
}
-(void)checkIfThePersonLoggedIn
{
    CredentialStore *credStore = [CredentialStore sharedStore];

//    //check to see if the use has the token already
    if (credStore.loginInfo.authToken != nil) {
        [self.loginButton setHidden:YES];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"welcomeViewSegue" sender:self];
    }
    else [self.loginButton setHidden:NO];
    NSLog(@"checkForToken - loginviewcontroller");
}
```

and in my getTokenRequest this is how I save the token in the event of success

```
 NSString *authToken = [responseObject objectForKey:@"Token"];
        CredentialStore *credStore = [CredentialStore sharedStore];
        LoginInfo * loginInfo = credStore.loginInfo;
        loginInfo.authToken = authToken;
        NSLog(@"this is the token here %@",authToken);
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"welcomeViewSegue" sender:self];
```

I appreciate the help.

this is where I instantiate login info

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
    [_usernameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [SVProgressHUD show];
    id LoginParams =@{
                 @"NickName" : self.usernameTextField.text,
                 @"password" :_StoreIdentifierForVendor,
                 @"DeviceType" :_DeviceModel
                 };
    [[AuthAPIManager sharedManager]POST:@"/url" parameters:LoginParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"response: %@", responseObject);

        LoginInfo *loginInfo = [[LoginInfo alloc] initWithDictionary:responseObject];
        CredentialStore *credStore = [CredentialStore sharedStore];
        credStore.loginInfo = loginInfo;
        [self getToken];

    }failure....
```

Comment: Please, add code where you instantiate LoginInfo object.

Comment: Have you checked that LoginInfo object is instantiated properly? and LoginInfo is not nil ?

Comment: Based on the two break points I put, login info gets the values just fine. But in my next view, I call one of the login info property to check if it saved correctly but I get a nil response. This is how I did it: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *exampleLabel;
@property LoginInfo *info;` and in .m view will appear `    self.exampleLabel.text = [_info NickName];
    NSLog(@"this is the username %@",_exampleLabel.text);` and I get nil for in nslog.

Comment: **Update** I am able to see the information that I saved. Apparently, i was creating a new instance, instead of calling with the shared one. But I am still unable to bypass the login. It keep skipping the `if (loginInfo.authToken != nil) {}` statement.